# error when using this in c++

Tags: c++, lvalue, towers-of-hanoi, gwt-history

```
class Tower
{
int index;//index of the tower;
nodeStack<int> t;
int size;//number of disks in the tower;

public:
Tower(int in);
void moveTopTo(Tower&);
void move(int size,Tower& dest,Tower& buffer);

};

void Tower::move(int n,Tower& dest,Tower& buffer)
{
    if(n>0)
    {
    move(n-1,buffer,dest);
    moveTopTo(dest);
    move(n-1,dest,this);
    }
}
```

in this line :move(n-1,dest,this);

got an error says initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue;

Answer (score 2):

You need to dereference your `this` pointer so that you can use it as a reference:

```
move(n-1, dest, *this);
```